# How to make multiple SLC region on eMMC User Area?

Tags: linux, partition, embedded, u-boot, mmc

I have to partition (i.e hardware partition) the UDA (User Data Area) of the eMMC as follows:

1. First 336MB region should be in pSLC.
2. Next 2GB region as MLC partition.
3. The remaining region again should be in pSLC mode.

I have already done complete eMMC region as pSLC and it got worked with the below command:

```
mmc hwpartition user enh <start> <size> wrrel on complete
```

However, I didn't get how to achieve the above combination of MLC and pSLC with the same command.

I have tried the below commands and none of them are working as expected.

1. Both region with **complete** flag:

   > mmc hwpartition user enh "first_region_start" "first_region_size"
   >   wrrel on **complete**
   >
   > mmc hwpartition user enh "second_region_start" "second_region_size"
   >   wrrel on **complete**

In this case, it failed because the first complete flag will not allow the second pSLC region update.

2. First region with **Set** flag and second region with **complete** flag:

   > mmc hwpartition user enh "first_region_start" "first_region_size"
   >   wrrel on **set**
   >
   > mmc hwpartition user enh "second_region_start" "second_region_size"
   >   wrrel on **complete**

This doesn't make any effect and not make enhanced too! After the power cycle, it shows the complete eMMC region as MLC itself.

Could anyone help me to figure out how to perform the mentioned partition combination?

Answer (score 1):

To partition the eMMC from u-boot, you need to perform 3 steps (i.e. set, check, complete) followed by power-cycle:

```
=> mmc hwpartition (user | gp1 | gp2) "region_size" [enh wrrel on] set
=> mmc hwpartition (user | gp1 | gp2) [enh] "region_size" [wrrel on] check
=> mmc hwpartition (user | gp1 | gp2) [enh] "region_size" [wrrel on] complete
```

Optional arguments:

- wrrel on : Turn on write-reliability
- enh      : Enhanced partition (configure the partition as SLC).
  Without this argument, the partition will take pSLC by default.

You should configure all the three partitions as one command of 'set', one command of 'check', and one command of 'complete'.

For your case the command will be roughly as follows:

```
=> mmc hwpartition user 688128 enh wrrel on user 4194304 wrrel on user wrrel on set
=> mmc hwpartition user 688128 enh wrrel on user 4194304 wrrel on user wrrel on set
=> mmc hwpartition user 688128 enh wrrel on user 4194304 wrrel on user wrrel on set
```

Note:

> HW partition is one time programmable (OTP). Once you do *'mmc hwpartition ... complete'* and performed power-cycle, your card will be programmed as whatever partitions you set.